# Why use explicit loop parameter with aiohttp?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The `aiohttp` library's [documentation](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_reference.html#basic-api) states:

> loop – event loop used for processing HTTP requests. If param is None, asyncio.get_event_loop() is used for getting default event loop, but we strongly recommend to use explicit loops everywhere. (optional)

It is possible to pass the `loop` to `ClientSession` objects, to provided "module-level" functions etc.

I am new to the asynchronous programming concept as a whole, could you explain to me *why* it's recommended to explicitely provide the loop to use, rather than letting the objects/functions just use the default?

One use that comes to mind is making testing easier, by being able to provide my own loop mocks, is there a performance reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is readability and not performance.

Specifying a loop explicitly will make it easier for a developer to see where the loop instance originates from, and might make it easier to change the loop if a custom loop needs to be injected to the program.

Another popular option would be to **never** specify the loop parameter, and therefore assume `asyncio.get_event_loop()` is always called to get a loop instance.

(It is possible to use more than one loop - for example in different threads, but this is not a common use case)