# Is there a difference between 'await future' and 'await asyncio.wait_for(future, None)'?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

With python 3.5 or later, is there any difference between directly applying `await` to a future or task, and wrapping it with `asyncio.wait_for`?  The documentation is unclear on when it is appropriate to use `wait_for` and I'm wondering if it's a vestige of the old generator-based library.  The test program below *appears* to show no difference but that doesn't really prove anything.

```
import asyncio

async def task_one():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return 1

async def task_two():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    return 2

async def test(loop):
    t1 = loop.create_task(task_one())
    t2 = loop.create_task(task_two())

    print(repr(await t1))
    print(repr(await asyncio.wait_for(t2, None)))

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(test(loop))
    finally:
        loop.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `wait_for` gives two more functionalities:

1. allow to define timeout,
2. let you specify the loop

Your example:

```
await f1
await asyncio.wait_for(f1, None)  # or simply asyncio.wait_for(f1)
```

besides an overhead of calling additional wrapper (wait_for), they're the same (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L318).

Both `awaits` will wait indefinitely for the results (or exception). In this case plain `await` is more appropriate.

On the other hand if you provide timeout argument it will wait for the results with time constraint. And if it will take more than the timeout it will raise `TimeoutError` and the future will be cancelled.

```
async def my_func():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return 'OK'

# will wait 10s 
await my_func()

# will wait only 5 seconds and then will raise TimeoutError
await asyncio.wait_for(my_func(), 5)
```

Another thing is the loop argument. In the most cases you shouldn't be bothered, the use case is limited: inject different loop for tests, run other loop ...

The problem with this parameter is, that all subsequent tasks/functions  should also have that loop passed along...

More info https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/362

- [Passing asyncio loop by argument or using default asyncio loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340493/passing-asyncio-loop-by-argument-or-using-default-asyncio-loop)
- [Why use explicit loop parameter with aiohttp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350334/why-use-explicit-loop-parameter-with-aiohttp)

Comment: Can you think of a situation where it would matter to be able to specify the loop?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the python documentation is a little bit unclear here, but if you have a look into the [sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/769ddb075ac3a840d473930a12a5b72bfbab366f/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L322) its pretty obvious:

In contrary to `await` the coroutine `asyncio.wait_for()` allows to wait only for a limited time until the future/task completes. If it does not complete within this time a `concurrent.futures.TimeoutError` is raised.

This timeout can be specified as second parameter. In your sample code this `timeout` parameter is `None` which results in *exactly* the same functionality as directly applying `await`/`yield from`.